# Granting Azure function console access without publish web site permission

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, kudu

I wish to grant users in a given AD group access to the Development Tools > Console function of the Production environment. I believe this is [Kudu permission granted by assigning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu) the [Microsoft.Web/sites/publish/Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations).

Is this possible without granting a member of the group the ability to publish web sites?

Answer (score 1):

> It is not possible to granting a member of the group the ability to publish web sites.

From the [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu) document it stated clear that you required `microsoft.web/sites/publish/action` resource provider operation.

> Ones with Kudu access are ones owning the site - regardless if
> read-only or not. To expand, they can deploy any codes (good or
> malicious) to and able to read any secret settings of the site (eg.
> KeyVault, SQL and Storage credentials, Private Certificates, etc.).
> Hence for Azure, only those with Contributor / Owner access (to be
> exact, with microsoft.web/sites/publish/action or, for slot,
> microsoft.web/sites/slots/publish/action) can access to Kudu (SCM).

Refer this [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service#security) for more information.